# Configure Function App Private Key binding using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to configure Function App Private Key binding to a Key Vault connection using PowerShell

I can successfully do it with Portal as shown below

[image: TLS/SSL Settings]

I have tried various iterations of the following command against the Function App and the App Service Plan but it seems this is not supported.

`Import-AzWebAppKeyVaultCertificate -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -KeyVaultName $vaultName -CertName $CertName -WebAppName "Don't think this CMDLet Supports Azure Functions"`

Can anyone suggest a workaround or the correct CMDLet for this?

When I configure it manually I can see it when I run
`Get-AzWebAppCertificate`

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working with this:

```
$appServicePlan = Get-AzAppServicePlan -Name $AppServicePlanName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName;
$PropertiesObject = @{
  keyVaultId         = $keyVault.ResourceId
  keyVaultSecretName = $ADServicePrincipalCertificateName
  serverFarmId       = $appServicePlan.Id
} 
New-AzResource -Name $ADServicePrincipalCertificateName -Location $kv.Location -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/certificates -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force;
```